# Python: How to extract the first instance of a value from an array and store it in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, loops, iteration

I am new to python. I have a list of values I want to check against in an array and store the first instance in a new single array.

my list is as follows:

```
list = ['1','2','A','B']
```

my array looks something like:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0  1    B    2    A
1  9    A    2    B
2  7    k    1    A  
3  I    2    1    A
4  9    3    B    3
5  W    Y    5    A
```

I want to use a for loop to iterate through the array matrix and find the first instance of the values in my list and store them in a new array.

```
new_array = ['1','A','2','B','A']
```

How can I do this?

if tried something like:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    if  array[i] in ('1','2','A','B'):
        new_array = i
```

This does not work however.

Here is my actual code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame('stat1':'1','stat2':'b','stat3':'2','stat4':'v',
        'stat5':'3','stat6':'v','stat7':'2','stat8':'1',
        'stat9':'c','stat10':'2','stat11':'2','stat12':'c',
        'stat13':'1','stat14':'x','stat15':'1','stat16':'c',
        'stat17':'c','stat18':'2','stat19':'2','stat20':'2',
        'stat21':'3','stat22':'1','stat23':'c','stat24':'1',},index=df.index)

stat =pd.as_matrix(columns=df.columns[:]) 


new_array = []

for n in range(0,23):    
        if stat[n] in ("3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A", "B", "E", "Q", "R", "Y",
                "L", "I", "J", "W", "AA", "AC", "AD") and new_array == []:
            new_array = n
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really follow your matrix. `1 1 3 4` seems to be at row -1? Where is `col0`? Is the left column actually part of the data? Can you show the exact Python structure? I'm also not sure I really follow you specifications, either. You just want to test whether each element from the array is in the matrix and store it into a result array? How do we get 2 `A`s? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by first instance? And anyway the list already consists the values you want to check.

Comment: Hi ggorlen, sorry for that. I've just edited my column names

Comment: by first instance I mean the first time any of the values in my list appear in the matrix. So if you look at row 0, all of the values are present in my list but the first  one identified is 1. So I want to extract 1 and place it in my new array.

Comment: OK, thanks, but the new version is also unclear. Can you just show the Python code? There'd be no ambiguity then. I don't understand why it's 1-indexed, and what the left column represents. It's unclear whether `1` in your pseudo-matrix is a string or not. As for your spec, you're asking for "the first time", but where did the extra `'A'` come from? Why did `'2'` and `'A'` switch places?

Comment: `array[i] in ('1', '2', ...)` will never be true, as `array[i]` is a list/tuple/etc.  Perhaps you meant `if any(item in ('1', '2', ...) for item in array[i])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
mat = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,3,2],[9,0,4,3]]
list = [1,5,4,3]
ans = []
for row in mat:
  for x in row:
    if x in list:
      ans.append(x)
      break
print(ans)
```

You can simply replace mat and list with your actual values.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can break the loop once the element found

```
res = []
for line in matrix:
    for ele in line:
        if ele in ('1','2','A','B'):
            res.append(ele)
            break
```